# Change meta title of customer login page

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, meta-tags

Trying to change the meta title of the customer login page in Magento2 at `example.com/customer/account/login/`. Added  tag to my xml file but no luck. Please advise.

Here's my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Member Login</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Member Login</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="newcustomer.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into where the title is set.  This is a function under `\Build\vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Form\Login.php`

It contains the following code -

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

You could override this with an extension, but the easiest is probably to translate "Customer Login" as "Member Login" (assuming you are happy for that to change in all places that the text appears, such as the page title).